# Programming language or library for simple GUI?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface

What is a programming language to make program with a GUI.  I know there is a way to make a GUI using C in Windows, but I want to program with Linux and make my programs compatible with other OS's as well.  Any recommendations?

Comment: Just have some fun with old school ncurses: http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/

Comment: HTML using an embedded web server?

Comment: Try C++/Qt, but you will have to compile for every OS. For nice tutorials of many GUI programming styles see http://zetcode.com/

Comment: Try GTK, nice and clean.

Comment: You are allrready programing Python: use PyQt for example.

Comment: There's also [X11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_System). You can run an X-server on [Windows](http://cygwin.com/) or Mac (and it's the standard GUI for Linux and other Unices).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is make a GUI, why don't you just use HTML?

Alternatively, if you really want it to be a more native app, maybe consider Java.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorials to help program in java

Answer (score 3):

> I know there is a way to make a gui with C in windows but I want to program with Linux

[Who told you that you can't write a GUI app in C on Linux...](http://www.gtk.org/)

Also, for whipping up quick GUIs, there's [wxPython.](http://www.wxpython.org/)

Comment: yeah theres also QT in C++

Comment: No-one said I can't make a gui in linux, I just haven't found a tutorial for it.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a GUI using the standard C library.  You can make one with an external library though.

With [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/), it is possible to make a GUI, and there is a large community behind the project.  You can find lots of code examples and tutorials on their website.  In addition, you can use OpenCV for lots of other [computer vision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_vision) related things.

You could also use [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) to write a GUI for your program.  It is very simple, and easy to use for beginners.  It's more focused on graphics though, and if you want another functionality required by an external library, you might not be able to use GTK+.